# thickbox image gallery

Tags: thickbox

if I display one image link from a folder how can I use this image to create a gallery for that folder using thickbox without having to display all images from the folder.

Comment: Found answer. Need to add a hidden div afterwards with the links of all the other images after the first thumbnail. Might be useful to anyone else who has had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add a hidden div afterwards with the links of all the other images after the first thumbnail. Might be useful to anyone else who has had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Btw. from the thickbox homepage

> While Thickbox had its day, it is not
>   maintained any longer, so we recommend
>   you use some alternatives.